# A question about properties of integrals

Tags: calculus, integration

Suppose g is differentiable with $g'(x)<0$ for all $x<1$, and $g'(x)>0$ for all $x>1$, and suppose $g(1)=0$. Now let $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt$.
Prove that G(x) is an increasing function (this is the last part of the problem).

My approach is that since $G'(x)=g(x)$, we just need to prove g(x)>0 for all x.
We know $\int_a^x g'(t)dt=g(x)$, and since g'(x)<0 for all x<1, then $g(x)=\int_a^x g'(t)dt<0$ for all $a\in(-\infty,1)$ and $x\in(a,1)$; also, since g'(x)>0 for all x>1, then $g(x)=\int_a^x g'(t)dt>0$ for all $a\in(1,\infty)$ and $x\in(a,\infty)$.
Here comes the question:
I know that for $x\in(-\infty,1)$, $G(x)=\int_0^x g(t)dt \Rightarrow G'(x)=g(x)$, and by the previous information we know $g(x)<0$ on the interval. Although by similar argument I can prove $G'(x)>0$ for $x>1$, but at this point I don't know if my reasoning is correct anymore.

So where lies the problem in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1):

Since $g^{\prime}(x)<0$ for $x<1$, $g$ is decreasing on $(-\infty, 1)$.
Similarly, since $g^{\prime}(x)>0$ for $x>1$, $g$ is increasing on $(1, \infty)$.
Since $g(1)=0$, this implies that $g(x)>0$ on $(-\infty,1)$ and on $(1,\infty)$.

As you say, $G^{\prime}(x)=g(x)$, so $G(x)$ is increasing on $(-\infty, 1]$ and on $[1,\infty)$, and therefore on $(-\infty, \infty)$.

---

The problem in your reasoning starts with the equation $\int_{a}^{x}g^{\prime}(t) dt=g(x)$, since you want to have $g(x)-g(a)$ on the righthand side instead.  If we take $a=1$ to simplify matters, this gives
$\int_{1}^{x}g^{\prime}(t) dt=g(x)-g(1)=g(x)$ since $g(1)=0$.  Notice that for $x<1$, this gives

$g(x)=\int_{1}^{x}g^{\prime}(t) dt=-\int_{x}^{1}g^{\prime}(t) dt= \int_{x}^{1}(-g^{\prime}(t)) dt > 0$ since by assumption $g^{\prime}(t)<0$ for $t<1$.